# Display a query as statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I would to run the query to be as a statement. Ex: hello world

I tried to do this

```
select concat('employee ', employeename, 'joined on ', doj, 'who gets' , salary , ' dept' , dept) 
from employee where emid=1;
```

And the output is invalid number of arguments.

Comment: Oracle's [`concat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CONCAT.html#GUID-D8723EA5-C93A-45C3-83FB-1F3D2A4CEAF2)  only accepts two parameters, not multiple. And you should use straight quotes `'` - **not** those typographic quotes `‘`

Comment: My guess is that you typed that query on a Mac, with smart quotes.  There is a way to disable them: https://www.iclarified.com/38772/how-to-disable-curly-quotes-in-mac-os-x-mavericks

Comment: Thank you. I am using my phone to write the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

use `||`

```
 Select 'employee' || employeename ||'joined on' || doj || 'who gets' || salary || dept 
 from employee where emid=1;
```

Comment: It's working, but as column. Who can I do it as a result to show data of employee 1

Comment: @sarahAH - um, *don't* use concatenation?